# Link on multiple fields, including null value

Tags: oracle, linker

I need to create a query (in Oracle) where I compare 2 tables. Both tables contain the same headers. I need to check if the lines are exactly the same. If they are not, I want to show them.
Problem is, that some fields could be empty. So I can't do a simple join.

Some sample data:

Table 1:
Street:            City:              Phone:             Phone 2:           Fax:
Example 1          Dublin             0123456789         0198765432
Example 2          London             0543210789

Table 2:
Street:            City:              Phone:             Phone 2:           Fax:
Example 1          Dublin             0123456789         0198765432         0111223344
Example 2          London             0543210789

In above example, I would only want to show the second example. I have about 6 fields that could be blank, so I don't really want to be describing every single possibility. Is there any way to link this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Kind regards

Gerben

Comment: if 1 of them is blank and the other isnt, you want the join to still suceed? and if both are blank? or both exist but are different? You example is not entirely clear on the expected results in different scenarios.

Comment: Use the `coalesce` function to turn your `null`s into something non-null that doesn't otherwise appear as a value for that column in your table. Then you can use a "simple" join on the `coalesce`d values.

Comment: You can check if both values are null: .. and (a.phone=b.phone OR a.phone is null and b.phone is null)

Comment: Or you can use the MINUS operator: select * from table1 MINUS select * from table2